# Return variable undefined in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I'm new in NodeJS, I'm trying to make a function and return a value, but when I call it it return "UNDEFINED", this is my code, I hope you guys can help me.

```
function getData (jsonData){
   var json;
   request(jsonData, function(error, response, body){
     if(body){
       json = JSON.parse(body);
     }else{
       json = error;
     }
   });

   return json;
}
```

Comment: I believe your body is inside your `response` instead of the third params of request callback.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As your request function is async operation, your function returns even before the callback of request is called, you can use of the following approaches.

**1. Callback Approach:** Make getData function a callback function, and call the callback once you get response in the body.

```
// Definition
function getData (jsonData, cb){
   request(jsonData, function(error, response, body){
     if(body){
       return cb(null, JSON.parse(body));
     }
     return cb(error);
   });
}

// Invocation
getData({}, function(error, response) {
  if (error){
    console.log(error);
    return;
  }
  console.log(response);
})
```

**2. Promises Approach:** Promises is a nice way to deal with async functions. Wrap your function inside a promise. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

```
// Definition
function getData (jsonData){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(jsonData, function(error, response, body){
      if(body){
        return resolve(JSON.parse(body));
      }
      return reject(error);
   });
  });
}

// Invocation
getData({})
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .error(error => console.log(error));
```

**3. Async Await Approach:** This is the new way of writing async functions in a synchronous way. For this nothing changes on the definition like promises as request uses callback.

```
// Definition
function getData (jsonData){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(jsonData, function(error, response, body){
      if(body){
        return resolve(JSON.parse(body));
      }
      return reject(error);
   });
  });
}

// Invocation if calling outside
(async() => {
  try {
    const response = await getJsonData({});
    console.log(response); 
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})();

// in another function
async function test() {
  const response = await getJsonData({});
  console.log(response);
}
```

Comment: I'm using the third way that is the best for me, but it shows me this error "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function"

Comment: @AlexAguilarMurillo updated my answer, you have to mark the function as async if you are using `getJsonData` in another function.